# What's the rails way to do buttons as simple links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a button (in a haml view) that I want to use to go to another controller/action.  I am more accustomed to PHP than rails.  What I have tried works but does not feel like the rails way.  Here are my 3 ways.  Can anyone offer suggestions?  I'd particularly like to see the way the button with a javascript onclick handler would be done.

```
%p
=link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path(@user)
%button.btn.btn-success.doEdit{:onclick => "window.location='#{edit_user_registration_path(@user)}'"} Edit
%button.btn.btn-danger.doEdit2 Edit
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.doEdit2').click(function(event) {
      window.location="#{edit_user_registration_path(@user)}";
  });
});
```

Comment: Something akin to:
%td= button_to('Index', people_path, :method => :get)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would normally not use a "button" per say. I would do this:

```
=link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path(@user), class: "btn btn-danger edituser"
```

The btn class would add the CSS styling to make it look like a button, but it would just be a link. To javascript handler to this:

```
$("a.edituser").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  doWhateverYouNeedHere();
});
```

Comment: The link with button styling seems the way to go.  Just thought rails might have some kind of native onclick attribute for a button.

Comment: Really depends on what you're after.. you can add "remote: true" and it'll turn into some ajaxy stuff, but it's usefulness is limited.

Answer (score 3):

[`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) is probably what you're after.

Comment: That seems to create a form surrounding the button.  Seems like overkill to me.