# Button set on Disabled but still I can click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is the HAML code I have:

```
 %a.btn.btn-primary.personlistbtn{href:patients_path, :target => "_blank", :disabled => 'disabled'} Person List
```

And this is how it looks on Inspect Element:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary personlistbtn" disabled="disabled" href="/patients" target="_blank">Person List</a>
```

so I have set it to `disabled`, and from how it looks it does look disabled because its color is lighter than the other normal buttons but still if I click on it, it is working. I also have this onclick code for its JavaScript part:

```
  $('.personlistbtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open("http://localhost:3000/patients?provider="+provider_id+"&"+"therapeutic_class="+thera_class);
  });
```

Is that JS the culprit? or how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a link (the `%a`) and giving the link a button class. The `disabled` attribute is styling it as a button properly but that doesn't disable links. Do you need a link or can you just use a button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007831/whats-the-rails-way-to-do-buttons-as-simple-links